# Understanding Xlib Failed Requests

Tags: x11, xlib

Without going into too much detail (I am looking for debugging techniques here), I would like to understand how to better debug Xlib failed requests. In particular dealing with the glx extension. The occurrence of the bug I am fighting is in a complex place within my application and trying to pull it apart to provide a small sample here is not possible.

With that said the failed request I am seeing is

```
x10:  fatal 10 error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0.0"
      after 46 requests (46 know processed) with 0 event remaining.
X Error of failed request: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request: 135 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request: 5 (XGLMakeCurrent)
  Serial number of failed request: 46
  Current serial number in output stream: 46
```

I can see where the problem is being caused by stepping through with the debugger. However, I can't fully discern why it is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue where to look is in the name of the extension and the name of the request itself. Unfortunately in this case because of your use of [Xgl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xgl) this isn't so helpful. But you can check what the request really is by checking out the protocol documentation like this one for [glproto](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/glproto/tree/glxproto.h#n2131). From that you can see that the request is really `glxMakeCurrent`. Then you just need to find the documentation or code for that request.

The [GLX](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glx/glx1.3.pdf) specification says `glxMakeCurrent` will give `BadAccess` if "the context is current to some other thread".

Now, your error is about `XGLMakeCurrent` which is an implementation detail of [Xgl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xgl) . But from reading the implementation of this function it passes through to the the underlying GLX implementation.

To fix your problem I suggest you try and identify if that context is being used in another thread.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging you want to turn on synchronous requests, this slows down your code but will make every X request wait until the server processes it before continuing and immediately return an error. You can turn it on with

```
XSynchronize(display, True);
```

Now you will get the X error at the routine that caused the issue and can use standard debugging tools from there.